# RTF Template - Excel output didn't display full data

Tags: oracle, bi-publisher

I created RTF Template from MS Word .I have problem which is wrapping of text in output excel cell.
Data gets wrapped in the output cell but full data is not visible when I open the xls file.

I tried :

-Uncheck Wrap text.

-resize width column .

-Check fit text.

-Check Automatically resize to fit content.

but it didn't work . Can anyone help me find what the problem is?

Regards ,

Mint

Comment: I remember when I had to output to excel with this requirement, I found the only option to be estimating the maximum required width and setting it in the template.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any formatting requirements, and you just need to export date into something Excel can easily work with, try e-text templates. Use the comma separated version, not the fixed width.